# Using the wildcard element (AIML) on botlibre for my chatbot

Tags: artificial-intelligence, chatbot, aiml, botlibre

my chatbot isn't responding to using a wildcard when used in the 1st way shown below.

```
<category>
<pattern>*</pattern>
<that>MY LITTLE HUMAN HELLO WHAT IS YOUR NAME</that>
<template>Owh, nice to meet you, <set name="name"><star/></set>. I should already know your name but my system is still getting used to your brain and the way things are stored here... Do you know who I am?</template>
</category>
```

The above one does not work. I can't just enter my name. BUT the one below works, when I put my name in a full sentence (it also works with other variations of a sentence, just not on its own):

```
<category>
<pattern>MY NAME IS *</pattern>
<template>Owh, nice to meet you, <set name="name"><star/></set>. I should already know your name but my system is still getting used to your brain and the way things are stored here... Do you know who I am?</template>
</category>
```

Not sure what my mistake is. I've tried changing things to play around with it but nothing's worked so far. Also tried googling and searching but am unable to find a solution that works (or maybe I'm searching the wrong thing?). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This is because your first category has a <that> tag in it and unless your bot has just said, "MY LITTLE HUMAN HELLO WHAT IS YOUR NAME", this category will never be called. The solution is to either remove the <that> tag or to amend it to whatever the bot has actually said.